# Create directory in C# without readonly attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, directory

When I try to do that:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory([folderPath]);
File.CreateText([folderPath]);
```

I had the exception -

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Access to the path 'C:\[folderPath]' is denied.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
       at System.IO.File.CreateText(String path)
       at Contest.Service.FileSystem.CreateFileAndFolderForAttempt(IAttempt attempt) in c:\Users\Mif\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Contest\Contest.Service\FileSystem.cs:line 33
       at Contest.Service.Tests.FileSystemTests.TestCreateFileAndFolderForAttempt() in c:\Users\Mif\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Contest\Contest.Service.Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 32
  InnerException:
```

File Explorer show me:

Attributes:    [tristate/indeterminate checkbox] Read-only (Only applies to files in folder)

But `Debug.WriteLine(CurrentContestDirectory.Attributes.ToString());`
Show me - `Directory`. And not the readonly attribute!

I looked for "Removing read only attribute on a directory using C#" in Google, but all answers don't help me.
What I need to do?

All code runs on my local machine with Windows 8. Admin account. And if I uncheck readonly attrinute manually, after code run it toggle back.

It's simple console app.

Now I manually create folder. It's have read-only by default.

attrib -r C:\new /s in cmd not working!!!

And if I uncheck read-only manually and click OK then if I click Properties - **read-only come back**

Comment: maybe this Read-only attribute is just inherited from some parent-folder?

Comment: It's directly on drive root. I don't know how set "C:\" not read-only.

Comment: Web/windows app? Maybe this is not a "readonly problem", but rather "insufficient rights problem"?

Comment: why do you use [folderPath] as a param for File.CreateText? it should be directory path + file name.

Comment: [folderPath] is template. It mean [folderPath] == "any path".

Answer (score 1):

try with this code:

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\newfolder");
 File.CreateText(@"c:\newfolder\textfile.txt");
```

Comment: you are using [folderPath] in both lines of code, make sure that your  second line: "File.CreateText" is pointing a file like "file.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I would verify that your application running this code itself has proper rights in Windows. For instance, right click the application and click "Run as administrator"

Comment: My Visual Studio ran with administrator rights. But if I run my ConsoleApplication.exe as administrator then exception throws.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.CreateText([folderPath]);
```

is probably wrong. Any attempt to create a file (or open a stream) when the file path is actually a folder path will end with

```
UnauthorizedAccessException
```

The exception is very misleading and ask you to look in all the wrong places. Been there, seen it.